# jquery hover effect, submenu disappears

Tags: jquery, dynamic, menu, hover

I'm using wordpress to dynamically create a navbar, and jquery to append a submenu to the nav-bar. Using jquery, when you hover over the second menu item, the submenu animates down and fades in. I created a jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/NWpBB/

It works, but not well. If you hover over the top right list item in the submenu, it disappears. It also seems a bit glitchy. Any idea on how I can improve the functionality of this hover effect given the jquery on the above js fiddle link?

Here is the jquery:

```
$("#menu-nav li:nth-child(2) a").append('<span id="dropdown"></span');

$(".hoverMenu").css({"opacity":"0"});
        $(".hoverMenu").appendTo("#menu-nav li:nth-child(2)");

        $("#menu-nav li:nth-child(2)").hover(function(){
            $(".hoverMenu").stop().animate({
                top: '38',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 500);
        }, function(){
            $(".hoverMenu").stop().animate({
                top: '-290',
                opacity: '0'
            }, 500);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved : http://jsfiddle.net/NWpBB/1/

You wanted to access only the direct "li" child of #menu-nav hence adding a ">" in between.

You have an other glitch : when you hover over the 0-opacity submenu, it starts to appear because it is told to by jQuery. You should make it display:none, not only hidden.

EDIT : last one solved http://jsfiddle.net/NWpBB/4/

Comment: THANKS so much, that did it! I am going to use hoverIntent as well.

Comment: +1 I would have done it slightly different though: instead of `$(".hoverMenu")` use `$(".hoverMenu", this)` and instead of `> li:hover` use `li.menu-item:hover` I think this would allow multiple submenus rather than just the one submenu. $0.02 http://jsfiddle.net/NWpBB/3/

Comment: @Khoury >> true. @OP I wouldn't bloat my application with hoverIntent. Just add a `.css("display","none")` and a `.css("display","block")` at the proper times